# Are there any iOS/Android libraries available for in-app image annotation?

Tags: image, image-editing

Are there any image editing libraries available that I can use to implement image annotation in my app. I need it for both Android and iOS.

This is what I want to implement in my app-

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photopen/id478887640?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

Comment: Did you end up finding anything or creating yourself? Stuck in the same position - just need simple arrow/circle annotation on an image. Thanks!

Comment: Any lib for android?

Answer (score 2):

I came across Jot while asking the same question.  It seems to be a great drop-in solution for simple annotation.

https://github.com/IFTTT/jot

(I'm not affiliated with this library/developer in any way).

Comment: is there a library available for android?

Comment: Please note jot is for iOS and as of this point in time, version is not available for Android.